# Can Set Response as ArrayBuffer Client Side but not using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, unirest

I have a client side form using XMLHTTPResponse that allows me to get response data saved as a file. It sets the response type as arraybuffer as follows before the rest of the blob conversion occurs:

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

I have been searching and finding multiple methods to create an arraybuffer, but none that detail how to take the response in node to an arraybuffer. I am using unirest as follows:

```
unirest.post('http://myvendorsapi/Upload_PDF')
  .headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' })
  .field('filename', filename)// Form field
  .attach('file', fileloc)// Attachment
  .end(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
     var returnfile = response.body;
     // Need logic to convert to arraybuffer
  });
```

How do I set the response type to an arraybuffer or convert my response to an arraybuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get more raw response data, I would ditch the unirest library and use something thinner such as [request](https://github.com/request/request). Unirest claims to 'parse responses' for you, which sounds like something that you don't want. 
If you simply want to save the raw response body to a file, using request, you could do something like this:

```
var formData = {
    filename: filename,
    file: fs.createReadStream(fileloc)
}
var req = request.post({url: 'http://myvendorsapi/Upload_PDF', formData: formData})
req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('OUTPUT FILE NAME'))
```

Comment: If I wanted to pipe this into a directory as a completed file, how would I do that? Would i just set a path in the createWriteStream? (ex. createWriteStream('uploads/myfile.png')

Comment: yep, as long as the directory exists, it will create the file IIRC

Comment: The other issue is that I need to pass a filename and my file I am uploading is stored in a directory. Any clues on how I could upload a file from a directory using request then push the response into a directory?

Comment: I understand more what you are saying now. The request you are making has to use multipart/form-data. Let me glance at the request docs. It should be pretty easy

Comment: Check out the forms section of the docs here: https://github.com/request/request#forms

Comment: This is where I got confused before. Is this where I would set the file request should upload? custom_file: {
    value:  fs.createReadStream('/dev/urandom'),
    options: {
      filename: 'topsecret.jpg',
      contentType: 'image/jpg'
    }
  }

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. I was almost there. Testing now.